# Table sorting do not work after ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, html

I have one table that use ajax response when I choose a drop-down date to show table.

```
    <!--datepicker-->


    <div class="col-md-4">
            <input type="text" name="date_po_month_picker" id="date_po_month_picker" class="form-control" placeholder="Date"/>
            </div>
   <!--button-->
 <div class="col-md-8">
        <input type="button" name="range" id="range" value="Prikaži" class="btn btn-success"/>
        </div>

<!--table that generate from ajax -->           

 <div id="purchase_order" class="table table-striped table-bordered">

<!--stady table header-->

    <table id="datatable" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
    <thead>
    <tr>
    <th style="text-align:center;">Agent</th>
    <th style="text-align:center;">Obrade</th>
    <th style="text-align:center;">Kontakti</th>
    <th style="text-align:center;">Zadržani</th>
    <th style="text-align:center;">Terminirani</th>
    <th style="text-align:center;">Coversion rate</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    </table>


<!--script for datepicker -->
<script>
        $('#date_po_month_picker').daterangepicker({
        format: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
        singleDatePicker: true,
        singleClasses: "picker_1",
         locale: {
                format: 'YYYY-MM-DD'
            }
        }, function(start, end, label) {
        console.log(start.toISOString(), end.toISOString(), label);
        });
    </script>

<!--script for ajax-->

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $('#range').click(function(){
            var From = $('#date_po_month_picker').val();
            var to = $('#to').val();
            if(From != '')
            {
                $.ajax({
                    url:"wb_statistika_po_danu_ajax.php",
                    method:"POST",
                    data:{From:From},
                    success:function(data)
                    {
                        $('#purchase_order').html(data);
                    }
                });
            }
            else
            {
                alert("Please Select the Date");
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
```

This is my ajax file:

```
if(isset($_POST["From"]))   
{                   $result = '';
$date_month = date("m",strtotime($_POST['From']));
$date_year = date("Y",strtotime($_POST['From']));
                    //get records from database
                    $sql_list = "SELECT Agent,count(datum_obrade) as obrada, 
                    count(case when datum_kontakta>0 then 1 end) as kontakti,
                    count(case when datum_vracanja>0 then 1 end) as zadrzani,
                    count(case when datum_terminacije>0 then 1 end) as terminacija 
                    from wb_base WHERE MONTH(datum_obrade) = '".$date_month."' AND YEAR(datum_obrade) = '".$date_year."' group by Agent";
                    $sql_list_result = $mysqli->query($sql_list);
                    $result .='
                    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered tablesorter">
                      <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th style="text-align:center;">Agentt</th>
                            <th style="text-align:center;">Obrade</th>
                            <th style="text-align:center;">Kontakti</th>
                            <th style="text-align:center;">Zadržani</th>
                            <th style="text-align:center;">Terminirani</th>
                            <th style="text-align:center;">Coversion rate</th>
                        </tr>
                      </thead>';




                    if($sql_list_result->num_rows > 0){ 
                        while($row = $sql_list_result->fetch_assoc())
                        { 
                    $str = substr(($row["zadrzani"] / $row["obrada"]*'100'),0,5);
                        $result .='

            <tr>
            <td style="text-align:center;">'.$row["Agent"].'</td>
            <td style="text-align:center;">'.$row["obrada"].'</td>
            <td style="text-align:center;">'.$row["kontakti"].'</td>
            <td style="text-align:center;">'.$row["zadrzani"].'</td>
            <td style="text-align:center;">'.$row["terminacija"].'</td>
            <td style="text-align:center;">'. $str .'%</td>
            </tr>';



}
    }
    else
    {
        $result .='
        <tr>
        <td colspan="5">Za navedeni mjesec nema rezultata</td>
        </tr>';
    }
    $result .='</table>';
    echo $result;
}
```

All this work great but when i click button the sorting header dissapear. Before i click button i have arrows for sorting in my column headers, but after click they are gone. I notice that sorting is generated by table id `id="datatable"`, I try to add `id="datatable"` to table in my ajax file but no help. this table is using datatables.net plugin to generate tables and funcionts. But i would like to  add sorting what every i can.

Comment: Probably your table script doesn't support that, could you send us name of lib you use for sorting?

Comment: [this](https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js) is the datatables js I am not expert but i this here is sorting defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're **overwriting** the HTML elements that [DataTables](https://datatables.net/) turned into a sortable table.
This destroys those elements (and anything that's been done to them) and replaces them with new elements.
As the elements are new, you'll need to make them "sortable" once more.

Just re-initialize the table after you've replaced it:

```
success: function(data) {
    // this replaces the content of that div
    $('#purchase_order').html(data);

    // so reinitialize that table
    $('#purchase_order > table').DataTable({
        // whatever options you want
    });
}
```

As an aside, since you're overwriting the content of the entire `div` (not just the table), if you don't want you overwrite the `script` tags below the table, you may want to consider closing off the `div` immediately after the `table`.

```
<!--table that generate from ajax -->
<div id="purchase_order" class="table table-striped table-bordered">

    <!--stady table header-->
    <table id="datatable" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th style="text-align:center;">Agent</th>
                <th style="text-align:center;">Obrade</th>
                <th style="text-align:center;">Kontakti</th>
                <th style="text-align:center;">Zadržani</th>
                <th style="text-align:center;">Terminirani</th>
                <th style="text-align:center;">Coversion rate</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
</div><!-- close this off here so the scripts below aren't overwritten by the AJAX call.
```

Comment: Thank you, I get you why it won't sort the column. In options i add `"ordering": true` and that worked. Thank you. Why was necessary to use `> table`

Comment: @rtstorm Since the table returned by your ajax does not have an `id` attribute, I merely used `> table` to target the table inside `purchase_order`. I could have used `#purchase_order table.tablesorter`, but your initial markup doesn't apply that class to the table. Using `#purchase_order > table` targets that table regardless of it comgin from your initial markup or your ajax call.

Answer (score -1):

I am trying to find the solution for you, so you can play with my code I am pasting below. Do necessary changes at your end.

```
$('#range').click(function(){
    var From = $('#date_po_month_picker').val();
    var to = $('#to').val();
    if(From != '')
    {
        $('#datatable').DataTable().destroy();
        $('#datatable').DataTable({
            "order": [[ 0, "desc" ]],
            "pageLength": 50,
            "ajax": {
                type: "POST",
                url: "wb_statistika_po_danu_ajax.php}",
                data: {From:From}
           }                    
        });
    }
    else
    {
        alert("Please Select the Date");
    }
});
```

//PHP

```
foreach(loop for your data to return) {
    $row = array();
    $row[] = 'col1 data';
    $row[] = 'col2 data';
    $row[] = 'col3 data';
    $row[] = 'col4 data';
    $row[] = 'col5 data';
    $row[] = 'col6 data';

     $data[] = $row;
}

echo json_encode(['data'=>$data]);
```